# jwt decode giving empty username in django unittest while using request.META

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-unittest

I am generating the token as follows:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=UserSerializer)
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

        payload = {
            'username': user.email,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, "secret", algorithm="HS256")

        response = Response()

        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
        return response
```

I am writing unittests in django with jwt. I am using the following method to authorize

```
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = resp_login.data.get("jwt"))
```

To retrieve the username from the token, I use the following code:

```
def get_payload(request):
    token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
    if not token:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', options={"verify_signature": False}, algorithms=['HS512'])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')
    return payload
```

However, I get the payload as follows:

```
{'username': '', 'exp': 1691987384, 'iat': 1691983784}
```

The whole code is hosted [here](https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/DjangoJWT/)

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some details on how you're generating the token?

Comment: @mamareza I have edited. Kindly take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saving Email as username if so you can get the right value like:

```
 payload = {
            'username': user.username,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }
```